# Where's this extra bottom border/padding coming from?

Tags: html, css, anychart

We use a pretty simple header/body/footer layout:

```
...
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="head">[header content goes here]</div>
<div id="body">[content goes here]</div>
<div id="foot">[footer content goes here]</div>
</div>
</body>
...
```

The css then simply makes sure that the footer is always at the bottom:

```
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
#container {min-height:100%;position:relative;}
#body {padding:10px;padding-bottom:2em;zoom:1;}
#head {padding:10px;}
#foot {position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;height:1em;}
```

This works perfectly well... until we add an AnyChart graph to the page, that is. The minute we do that, instead of the footer being at the bottom of the page, there's a blank stripe that's the exact same height as the footer at the bottom of the page, and then the footer is above that blank stripe.

Here's what the problem looks like on a page that uses the "wide" stylesheet, which uses the full width of the browser for the content:
[image: Extra bottom border with no background image]

And here's what it looks like on a page that uses the "pretty" stylesheet, which adds a background image and side margins to let said image show through:
[image: Extra bottom border with background image]

I can make the space smaller by setting a negative border-bottom on #container, but I really want to know where it's coming from so I can fix the error instead of treating the symptom.

I'm having trouble making AnyChart cough up version information. I know it's not the latest version: it still uses extensive xml, both for templates and for the chart data, whereas I believe the newest version has moved mostly to JSON (or something like it). In our version, we add links to `AnyChart.js` and `AnyChartHTML5.js`, and then do stuff like this to define a graph (classic ASP with VBScript, if anyone cares):

```
<%
chartData = "<anychart><templates path=""../js/AnyChartTemplates.xml""/>"
chartData = chartData & "<charts><chart template=""relbar"">"
chartData = chartData & "<data><series><point name=""Question 1"" y=""4.5"" />"
chartData = chartData & "<point name=""Question 2"" y=""8.23"" />"
...
chartData = chartData & "</series></data><chart_settings>"
chartData = chartData & "<axes><y_axis><scale maximum=""10"" /></y_axis></axes>"
chartData = chartData & "</chart_settings></chart></charts></anychart>"
%>
<div id="mychart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    AnyChart.renderingType = anychart.RenderingType.SVG_PREFERRED;
    var chart = new AnyChart("../swf/Chart.swf");
    chart.setData('<%=chartData%>');
    chart.write("mychart");
</script>
```

Again, I want to emphasize that the styling works perfectly on every page that doesn't have an AnyChart graph on it, so the problem must lie with something AnyChart does. I know that there are other bugs with this version of AnyChart, e.g. if you have more than one chart on a page, it adds an `iframe` element which it tries to hide but fails miserably at doing so (as a workaround, our AnyChart css has a line `iframe {display:none;}`, which'll work as long as we don't want to actually use an iframe in the same page as a chart). I'm hoping someone knows what other superfluous element or styling AnyChart is adding that causes the bottom margin effect, so I can hide it or disable it.

Comment: Using Chrome or Firefox with Firebug could help. With Chrome you can right click an element and inspect. On the "Styles" tab, at the end, there is a layout that shows padding, border and margin. You can search what element is taking your precious space, passing the mouse over each element on the code shown will show on the page a color mask of padding and margin of it. Then look above it, the inheritance of css properties. You must be able to find the element and rule.

Comment: @fbiazi: Inspect Element doesn't think there's anything there. I tried in IE, Chrome, and Firefox. (I apologize, I should have mentioned this in the question.) What I mean is, you know how if you point at elements, they get highlighted, and their properties are displayed in the sidebar/bottom bar? If I point at the blank space, nothing gets highlighted.